# Using CodeKit 2 with Wordpress/Bootstrap via Bower

Tags: bower, codekit

This may be a really dumb question but I've been searching the interwebs and haven't really found much helpful information. I have CodeKit 2 and I want to use Wordpress and Bootstrap in a project. I've never used Bower before but it looks really cool and I thought I'd give it a shot with CodeKit. I installed Wordpress, JQuery, and Bootstrap through the assets tab in my project and they installed into bower_components. In the video from Bryan Jones showing off Bower, he says not to move anything out of that folder or CodeKit won't see it as an asset anymore.

So my question is: how do I go about building my project from here? Obviously I don't want to have to run from the bower_components folder to do everything. In the Bower docs it says the easiest way is to just statically link the components you want. But I don't really understand how that would work with Wordpress and it seems like there'd be a better way to do it with CodeKit.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm thinking the same. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Steve I ended up just downloading Wordpress the old fashioned way for now. I'm using Bootstrap by having Codekit compile the variables.less and bootstrap.less files and including them in my own styles.less file in my theme.

Comment: Me too. Maybe I'm missing something. I can't see how keeping the files in the bower_components folder makes anything easier. Seems like it's simply a convenient download folder. Thanks for the reply. Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use Bower to manage wordpress, since wordpress can update itself very easily.

I think the best approach to building a WP site with Codekit is described in this tutorial: [Use CodeKit 2.0 for Local WordPress Development](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-codekit-20-for-local-wordpress-development--cms-19402).

Basically:

1. setup wordpress locally, any way you like, and use MAMP or AMPPS to serve the site.
2. drag your *theme folder* into Codekit - the theme is the project.
3. In the Browser Refreshing section of your project settings, use the external server option.  Paste in the local URL for your new WP site.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an article](https://medium.com/@yankeyhotel/with-great-bower-comes-great-responsibility-2ab630f2d35a) with some details.

Basically you just need to install `bootstrap.less` and `variables.less` in your `/less` folder, and then point your `@import` commands to your `/bower_components` folder. While you technically are running things out of `/bower_components`, after it's set up, you'll never know the difference.

Comment: I guess I understand how to go about using Bootstrap but I'm failing to see how to go about using Wordpress via Bower. Seems tricky to download via Bower and then install somehow without moving it out of the bower_components folder. Thinking about it, Bower probably isn't meant to install WP since WP isn't technically a front end thing. I've been using Bower quite a bit and have learned more of how it works and it seems like managing a WP installation wouldn't be a good use.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful thing about having wordpress connected to Bower is that you can just get the files downloaded quickly without having to grab the latest zip.

It makes sense to move the wordpress files to the top level, or where ever you are used to putting them.